# Error al querer editar en un crud

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

TENGO UN CRUD PERO AL EDITAR LOS VALORES INGRESADOS, SE VISUALIZA LA INTERFAZ PERO ME MARCA ERRORES.

Para registrar se llama registrar_ActCirc y el código es

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST["oculto"]) || empty($_POST["codigo"]) || empty($_POST["nombre"]) 
|| empty($_POST["naturaleza"]) || empty($_POST["descripcion"])){
    header("Location: inicio_ActCirc.php?mensaje=registro_error");
    exit();
}
include("model/conexion.php");
$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$naturaleza = $_POST["naturaleza"];
$descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];

$sentencia = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO activo_circulante (codigo,nombre,naturaleza,descripcion) VALUES (?,?,?,?);");
$resultado = $sentencia->execute([$codigo,$nombre,$naturaleza,$descripcion]);

if ($resultado === TRUE) {
    header("Location: inicio_ActCirc.php?mensaje=registro_exitoso");
} else {
    header("Location: inicio_ActCirc.php?mensaje=registro_error");
    exit();
}

?>
```

Para editar se llama editar_ActCirc y el código es

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['codigo'])){
        header('Location: inicio_ActCirc.php?mensaje=error');
        exit();
    }

    include_once 'model/conexion.php';
    $codigo = $_GET['codigo'];

    $sentencia = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM activo_pasivo where codigo = ?;");
    $sentencia->execute([$codigo]);
    $cuentas = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //print_r($cuentas);
?>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Editar datos:
                </div>
                <form class="p-4" method="POST" action="editar_proceso_ActCirc.php">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Código: </label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="codigo" required 
                        value="<?php echo $cuentas->codigo; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Nombre: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" required 
                        value="<?php echo $cuentas->nombre; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Naturaleza: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="naturaleza" autofocus required
                        value="<?php echo $cuentas->naturaleza; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Descripción: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" autofocus required
                        value="<?php echo $cuentas->descripcion; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-grid">
                        <input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $cuentas->codigo; ?>">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Editar">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include 'template/footer.php' ?>
```

Pero al entrar a editar me arroja la interfaz pero en el textbox del nombre aparece

> **Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type
> bool in **C:\xampp\htdocs\contabilidad\editar_ActCirc.php** on line
> **34**

el mismo error en naturaleza y descripción
Espero puedan darme una idea gracias

Comment: Si te dice que el value es bool será porque la consulta ha devuelto un false en lugar de una fila, por lo tanto o bien la consulta esta mal o bien el dato suministrado no arroja ningun resultado.  Yo probaria quitando el `;` final de la consulta, no tiene sentido en una sentencia prepare, y si aún así no funciona activaria el `print_r($cuentas);` para estar seguro que esta devolviendo algo.

Comment: HOLA YA QUITÉ EL ; DEL EXECUTE Y ME MARCA ERROR
YA ACTIVÉ EL PRINTR PERO NO DEVUELVE NADA. VOY A SEGUIR CHECANDO GRACIAS

Comment: haz la consulta a mano en phpmyadmin, es decir, coges el código ese que le pasas y lo pruebas en la consulta `SELECT * FROM activo_pasivo where codigo =` pero dentro del phpmyadmin.  De este modo veras si te devuelve algo, da un error, o no te devuelve nada, pues diria que el problema esta en la consulta en si, no en el php.